# How to get an HTML tag with comment in parse5-traverse?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

I use [parse5-traverse](https://github.com/JPeer264/parse5-traverse) to get comments of an HTML text file.

I have an HTML example:

```
<template>
   <!-- This is a header -->
  <div class="header">
    Hello, my name is
  </div>
  <div class="name">
    <!-- This is a slot -->
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

I wrote the code with the library:

```html
const htmlDoc = parse5.parse(htmlText, { sourceCodeLocationInfo: true, treeAdapter: htmlparser2Adapter });
traverse(htmlDoc, {
    pre(node: any, parent: any) {
        if (node['type'] && node['type'] === 'comment') {
            const data = <string>node['data'];
...
```

I can extract comment but how to get the comment and related tag?
Like this:

```js
[
   {
      "comment": "This is a header",
      "tag": "<div class=\"header\">"
   },
   {
      "comment": "This is a slot",
      "tag": "<slot><\/slot>"
   }
]
```